# Entanglement thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Consider two drummers: W and E.  They meet in the middle of the country and synchronize.  W strikes his drum on the up-beat, E on the down-beat.  They remain forever permanently synchronized, each with a pendulum swinging side-to-side (50% time to left, 50% of time to right).

W goes to the West coast, E goes to the East coast.

If I measure W striking his drum and hear a thump, and, 3 billionth of a second later measure silence from E, why is this surprising?

Silly to say, but if E was killed in an explosion 4 billionth of a second after W struck his drum (or even at the precise moment W struck his drum) then silence of E could mean either A) faster-than-light information transfer about the future...that E will be striking his drum soon, or B) E is dead.  In other words, 2 possible outcomes from the same measurement.

I don't get how "spooky at a distance" is spooky IF one assume that the overall wave function of a particle remains encoded with all interactions it's had previously with all other entangled particles.  I.e., if an entangled particle remains synchronized with respect to all other particles...then no FTL information transfer occurs.  Rather, it's just a matter of when you measure wandering drummers (who themselves are encoded with information which direction to be pointing when).

I am sorry if this is not clear.  I'm hoping there's some theory/paradox/something I can read more about this.

Thank you!

Comment: The thought experiment with drummers is quite unrelated to entanglement. You need to read about entanglement before asking a question. You can easily find a great deal on it, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you think we should think that "silence" is "surprising" here? Are you thinking of something specific you read about entanglement?

Comment: My intuition's interpretation of the testing of Bell's theorem causes me to reconcile...of all things...root 2, Hippasus, and the reason why 1/sqrt(2) is used in determining singlet and T0 quantum states.  I'm too dumb to recognize all that I'm not considering, but my neophyte read on the entanglement problem is that it's a perception about perception issue, not a real problem (that I can otherwise convolute into the Reimann hypothesis...why the zeta function zeros are at 1/2).  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You ask the right question, but your question does not include two things:

1. There is a weakness in the pairwise production of entangled photons. If the first photon is directed at 0°, the second is antiparallel. But the one could be directed in any direction (the second will always be antiparallel).
2. The measuring instruments could be polarisation foils. You have to align the foils as you want: 0° or 123.456°. Either way, the entanglement will be statistically detected. Say you achieve correlation in 25% of the simultaneous measurements.

So your conclusion is very correct. First, we convinced ourselves that we have designed an entanglement, and now we are not sure about it.

What collapses during the measurement is not the entangled state, but our not knowing (in say 25% of the cases).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and clear answer.  I suppose that an underlying premise of my question relates to the timing of measurement.  Of the tests I've read/seen on Bell's theorem, what seems consistent is (from my perspective) that measurements are weighted average of angular moments over time, where hidden variables are purportedly excluded, or, are same-time observations (e.g. polarization films) where observations are same-time